# How to change background colour of a layout and keep that colour for ever

Tags: android, xml, background, onclick

What I want to do is to change colour of  a layout when I click on a button, but however I want that colour to be what ever I have changed it to for ever. At the minute what it does is, it changes the colour to what I specified but if I go back or reopen the program it goes back to normal stage.

XML file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#fffcfdff"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="381dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#5DAD68"
        android:id="@+id/toppartofthescreen">

<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/backgroundcolour"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="133dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Java FIle;

```
public class ChangeBackground extends FragmentActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.example_layout);

findViewById(R.id.backgroundcolour).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           findViewById(R.id.toppartofthescreen).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffad4843"));

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: You have to keep your colour for example in shared preferences and set it when you go to application

Comment: How to go about doing that ? is that going to be too complex to implement ?

Comment: Okay, It's just I have never done anything like this before

Comment: Inform me that my solution work as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep your colour for example in `SharedPreferences` and set it when you go to application. Update your code as is shown in the example below:

```
public class ChangeBackground extends FragmentActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example_layout);
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int color = sharedPreferences.getInt("color", -1);
        if(color != -1){
            findViewById(R.id.toppartofthescreen).setBackgroundColor(color);
        }
        findViewById(R.id.backgroundcolour).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                findViewById(R.id.toppartofthescreen).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffad4843"));
                sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("color",Color.parseColor("#ffad4843") ).apply();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that code you provided but after going back and coming back into the app, the colour changed to what it was before. So it didn't store it into the shared preference

Comment: try it now sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("color",Color.parseColor("#ffad4843") ).apply();

Comment: just add .apply() method

Comment: Quick question if you don't mind, can I change background of something which is not in the same file ? so is there anyway I could change a background colour of something which is in a different xml file ? because when I try doing it I am getting Null Pointer Exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74417/discussion-between-jomin-george94-and-konrad-krakowiak).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using SharedPreferences:

```
 final SharedPreferences preference  = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(preference.getBoolean("showBgColor", false))
    {
        findViewById(R.id.toppartofthescreen).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffad4843"));
    }

    findViewById(R.id.backgroundcolour).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!preference.getBoolean("showBgColor", false)) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("showBgColor", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            findViewById(R.id.toppartofthescreen).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffad4843"));

        }
    });
```